# How should I handle different failure scenarios during Django authenticate()?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views

I'm writing a custom authentication backend in Django 1.7 and it could fail for one of two reasons: invalid credentials or some kind of internal error, e.g. a database issue.  Depending on the failure, I want to provide a different error message to the user. IE "Username or password is incorrect" for invalid credentials, and something like "An error occurred, please try again or contact support".

Since `authenticate()` needs to return a User model, I can't just return the error, so what I'm wondering is this: what is the best way to bubble the error up to the View that called `authenticate()`?

I'm leaning towards throwing an exception from `authenticate()` with the appropriate error message and then catching that exception in the view.  I think this is the best way to handle it, however I'm a far stretch from a Django expert so I'd love to hear what the community thinks.

Is throwing an exception my best option here, or is there a better way to bubble up authentication failures from `authenticate()` to the View?  And if throwing an exception is my best option, is there a predefined Django exception that would fit the bill, or should I make my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using try/except blocks in my View with custom errors that represent the relevant failure.

Answer (score 0):

In custom method First with `try except` you can catch the db error

In custom method user object will have `check_password` method

```
>>> try:
     user = User.objects.get(email='lennon@thebeatles.com')

    except:
        print("error with connection")
```

And after that using `check_password` method you will get the password error

```
    >>> user = User.objects.get(email='lennon@thebeatles.com')
    >>> user
    <User: john>
    >>> user.check_password('johnpassword')
    True
    >>>
```

Comment: I'm not concerned with how to properly catch the different failure points, I have that covered. I'm wondering how to bubble the errors up to the view that called authenticate().  I'm realizing now that I didn't make that overtly clear in the question, so I've reworded to make that more clear.

Comment: The best thing that you coluld do is generate validator methods for the errors before they raise an exception. or maybe should generate the errors and catch the raised exception.